# How to test ignoring some test files in golang?

Tags: go

I used to use `go test ./...` in CI. This will test all `xxx_test.go` files. But now I want this testcase to ignore some test files in a folder which is ended with `-TestClient`. What to do?

For example:

```
XFolderTestClient
    | -- xxx_test.go                    x
    | -- xxx2_test.go                   x


AnotherFolder
    | -- yyy.go                         √
...
```

I only want to ignore test files in folders  ending with TestClient.

3Q~

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.SkipNow

Comment: @frankegoesdown 3q, but it's inaccessible……

Comment: How about build tags? Anyway: Your requirement looks fishy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `run` flag to pass a regex/pattern ala:

`go test -run YourRegex`